Azure Custom Resource in Bicep
Could somebody share some insights in how to use an Azure Custom Provider Resource, that was published in another subscription , within Bicep?
Doing the same via cli (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/tutorial-custom-providers-create?tabs=azure-cli#create-a-custom-resource) already works like a charm for me
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders",
            "name": "xxx",
            "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "myCustomAction",
                        "routingType": "Proxy",
                        "endpoint": "functionappurl"
                    }
                ],
                "resourceTypes": [
                    {
                        "name": "myCustomResources",
                        "routingType": "Proxy",
                        "endpoint": "functionappurl"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}


Are you facing any error while trying to create it. @El Gohr

At the moment I was tinkering around with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.customproviders/associations?pivots=deployment-language-bicep and various error messages. Not sure if this template is meant for this purpose at all, but was the only one that I could find that somehow sounds like using the custom provider.

Have you checked this resource. @El Gohr

This template is used for providing - so yes. But I would like to use it


resource customProvider 'Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders/myCustomResources@2018-09-01-preview' = {
  name: 'myCustomResource/any'
  location: location
  properties: { 
    custom: 'test'
  }
}

Alright, got it.
The thing that confused me was switching {myCustomResource} and {myCustomResources}, which is switched within the resource definition.
So I'm just missing how to share this provider across subscriptions...

I have created a custom provider using Json template by referring to the given MSDoc and was deployed successfully.
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders",
            "name": "myCustomProvider",
            "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "myCustomAction",
                        "routingType": "Proxy",
                        "endpoint": "https://sampleaps.azurewebsites.net?code=APH3aFJeUmBU5x2pNOR_ZiUoiOUsJIYFFYinYi0cdxopAzFuI3c_KA=="
                    }
                ],
                "resourceTypes": [
                    {
                        "name": "myCustomResources",
                        "routingType": "Proxy",
                        "endpoint": "https://sampleaps.azurewebsites.net?code=APH3aFJeUmBU5x2pNOR_ZiUoiOUsJIYFFYinYi0cdxopAzFuI3c_KA=="
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}



Once it is deployed, you can refer it using existing keyword in a bicep file which you are going to create.
param customprovidername string = 'myCustomProvider'
resource existingprovider 'Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders@2018-09-01-preview' existing = {
  name: customprovidername
}
resource respname 'Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders/mycustomProvider@2018-09-01-preview' = {
  name: '${customprovidername}/newres'
  location: 'EastUs'
  properties: {}
}


Did you add the custom provider in resourceGroup Jahnavi (the one that is used for for usage of the provider later)?
When I try to deploy a custom provider resource outside of the resourceGroup where I deployed it, I'm getting {"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"The Resource 'Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders/x' under resource group 'y' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"}]}

Make sure that you have the customprovidername correctly and use targetScope as subscription. @ElGohr

use targetScope as subscription could you please elaborate on this?

targetScope = 'subscription' Add this line on the top of the code. @ElGohr

Alright, I guess I see where you want to go.
The property "scope" is not allowed on objects of type "Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders". Permissible properties include "asserts", "dependsOn", "tags". If this is an inaccuracy in the documentation, please report it to the Bicep Team.
with
resource customProvider 'Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders@2018-09-01-preview' = {   name: 'myProvider'   location: location   scope: tenant()

Yes scope is not allowed. That is why asking to use targetscope. @ElGohr

targetScope = 'subscription'
results in Scope "subscription" is not valid for this resource type. Permitted scopes: "resourceGroup".

Can you try adding resourceGroup once. @ElGohr

Already did, in this way the resource wouldn't be accessible within a different subscription...

Can you copy the customer provider resource ID manually and store it in a variable to access in the current code. @ElGohr

Wouldn't this be a big security issue if everybody could just guess resource ids for using customer providers? But I'll give it a try

Doesn't work to use it manually
